# Excel Fill all Dates Between Two Dates Across A Row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a start date (today) and some end date and would like to list every day between the two across a single row. I have used the sequence function but it spills down the column as opposed to horizontally to the right. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you post the formula you tried?

Comment: Use the `TRANSPOSE` function.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio there is no need for that as SEQUENCE allows for columns instead of ROWS.

Comment: @ScottCraner You are 100% correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use the columns in the SEQUENCE:

```
=SEQUENCE(,B1-A1+1,A1)
```

Where A1 is the Start date and B1 is the End date.

[image]

Comment: This should work, but I'm getting a #Value error saying that one of the values listed in the formula is of the wrong data type.

Comment: is the date in A1 a true date and not text that looks like a date?  Also what did you use that spilled vertically?

Comment: @fruityflex it's better to share a simple sample to show more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

I need to fill "1" between two different dates.
E.g

01.01.2022..Lunch   to  12.01.2022 Dinner

Now
If in sheet1 cell A1 is initial date and B1 is lunch

And C1 is end date and D1 is dinner....

Result should be in sheet2

Fill "1" between two dates in the sheet 2

Dates are in rows 1st to 31st in A1 to AD1

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1121942)